# ¿Qué significa esto en esta sobrecarga del operador?

Tags: c++

viendo un código que sobrecarga el operador + me asalta una duda:

```
Numero Numero::operator +(int numeros) const
{
    Numero salida(*this);
  salida = salida + (numeros);
    return salida;
}
```

La línea que contiene:

```
Numero salida(*this);
```

¿Qué hace exactamente?
Define un objeto tipo Numero?
Es que no lo entiendo bien, en teoría, lo que hace ese operador es dado sobre un número, le suma lo que esté en el parámetro números. 
Es decir, si tengo el objeto un valor 4 y recibe 3 en teoría devuelve 3, pero no entiendo bien esa línea qué hace.

Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Fíjate bien en como está declarada la función:

```
Numero Numero::operator+( int numeros ) const
```

Devuelve un `Numero` *por valor*, y el `Numero` original **no sufre cambios** (para eso está el `const` al final).

Ahora, observemos el cuerpo:

```
Numero salida( *this );
```

Crea *una copia* del valor original (recuerda, **no podemos moficarlo**).

```
salida = salida + numeros;
```

A esa copia, le suma el argumento.

```
return salida;
```

Devuelve el resultado de la operación anterior; es decir, devuelve la suma del argumento sobre el resultado.

Ya sabemos lo que hace *en teoría*; en la práctica ... pues depende del compilador: o el programa se bloquea en esa función y nunca llega a salir, o bien directamente obtenemos una *violación de segmento*.

Answer (score 1):

Esa línea declara una variable de tipo Numero con el nombre "salida" que hace referencia al objeto con el que se ha llamado al operador, por ejemplo si declaramos un objeto Numero, lo llamamos num y llamamos al operador +, dentro de la función operador la variable salida será una referencia a num.

```
Numero num1();
Numero num2=num1+3; //en esta llamada, "salida" hace referencia a "num1"
```